# Unable to call srec_cat via python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, srec-cat

I'm trying to call `srec_cat` from inside a python script by using the subprocess module, but it doesn't seem to work.
Calling `.\bin\srec_cat.exe c:\\temp\\2.hex -Intel -o c:\\temp\\2.srec -Motorola` just works fine, but calling `srec_cat` by utilizing the subprocess module like this

```
# build_s19_demo.py
import subprocess

parameter = 'c:\\temp\\2.hex -Intel -o c:\\temp\\2.srec -Motorola'
output = subprocess.run([".\\bin\\srec_cat.exe", parameter], capture_output=True)
print (output)
print (output.stderr.decode('ASCII'))
```

doesn't seem to work:

```
┖  python .\build_s19_demo.py
CompletedProcess(args=['.\\bin\\srec_cat.exe', 'c:\\temp\\2.hex -Intel -o c:\\temp\\2.srec -Motorola'], returncode=1, stdout=b'', stderr=b'srec_cat: c:\\temp\\2.hex -Intel -o c:\\temp\\2.srec -Motorola: open: Invalid\r\n    argument\r\n')
srec_cat: c:\temp\2.hex -Intel -o c:\temp\2.srec -Motorola: open: Invalid
    argument
```

Can anybody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The command has *five* parameters, not one.  The list you pass to `subprocess.run()` should therefore have six elements, including the command itself.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you, `subprocess.run([".\\bin\\srec_cat.exe", 'c:\\temp\\2.hex', '-Intel', '-o', 'c:\\temp\\2.srec', '-Motorola'], capture_output=True)` did the trick